# .htaccess : Multiple RewriteCond is not working. serer error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to route two domains(one is main domain & another is subdomain) to another folder by .htaccess, I am getting 500 error on the second domain.

I can't log the error so I am unable to give any error reasons.

### my directory structure is

```
public_html
  - main
  - blog
  - .htaccess
```

& root .htaccess file is -

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't log the error"? Certainly you can look into your log files in your development setup? Or are you trying to say that everything works fine in the development setup but fails on some live environment?

Comment: What certainly jumps into view is that you create endless rewriting rules. Since your generic patterns again match what you rewrote to.

Comment: it's on shared hosting with Cpanel. It seems that the errors log are not working properly.

Comment: So what do you see in your log files in your development setup?

Comment: i did't use any development server.

Comment: 1st this was the main website.now i need to add blog under subdirectory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205029/discussion-between-vickey-sharma-and-arkascha).

Comment: How do you expect to be able to develop then? You _can not_ develop on a production environment. Why? _Because you cannot log and debug ..._

Comment: Do your main domain and subdomain both point to the same place on the filesystem? ie. the document root of the main domain? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? If you request `/main/<url>` or `/blog/<url>` do these work serve your content as expected?